# Operation is Not Supported - System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile()

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Just installed our application on a client's server, and we are seeing an error that we have never seen before.  This program runs on hundreds of computers and servers around the world, and apparently this one is different.  Our client is fairly security conscious, so I'm guessing we need to have them unlock something, but no idea where to start.  Google search of the issue only gives me a bunch of PowerShell references.

When calling System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile() to load in a DLL, we receive an "Operation is not supported" error.

This is a .NET 4.0 C# application.

Thanks

Comment: There should be more information in that `Exception`.  I would log the entire exception with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a compiled application, running on a client server that we cannot debug on.  I'll do some more digging to see if I can find more in the event log.

Comment: What's different about the problematic computer? Is it in a different language? Different CPU (32bit vs 64bit)? All pre-requisite (.NET Framework 4.0, ...) are fully installed? etc.

Comment: Seems to be a fairly standard 64bit 2008 R2 server.  The client has a lot of security policies in place, so I my first thought is that they have code execution policies running that break calling DLLs as needed.

Comment: Looking with ILspy at LoadFile calls `CheckLoadFileSupported` which calls `AppDomain.IsAppXModel()` that seems to check if it is loaded and/or is an Windows8 appstore app. If it is it raises the exception you see. Not sure if it helps but check [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx) or  [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_store/all-modern-apps-fail-to-start-after-windows-81/a80793c7-c214-43ec-9ca9-5c758f9ad840?auth=1)

Comment: This is actually a Windows Service, rather than a desktop application.  I looked at the links posted, but unfortunately, I'm not sure they apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to each non-working DLL, properties, UNBLOCK.  Restarted our service, and everything started working.